# My android app is not available for tablets on google play

Tags: android, google-play

I made an android app for ordering a cab. I uploaded it on goole play and everything was fine until i tried to find the app over a tablet. I cannot find the app on google play. I googled the problem and i put the screen size in the manifest but its still not working.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".splash"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"        />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity
        android:name=".order"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity
        android:name=".personal"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity
        android:name=".flight"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

    <activity android:name=".details"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
</application>
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is in `"android.permission.CALL_PHONE"` permission that might not be available for tablets. You should add additional entry that shows that is not absolutely required feature and then handle that scenario in your code when you are accessing those features.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```

[Android documentation for `<uses-feature>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should place screenshots for the Tablet Portion as well as the requirements needed by the Google Play for Tablets.

Answer (score 0):

You should put all requirements for tablet and create .xml file for tablet in app layout folder and Screenshot for tablet. see more from [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/guide/practices/screens_support.html)