# Tablets are not able to find my app on the Google playstore

Tags: android, incompatibility

I have published my app on the google playstore with the tags specifying the compatibility for larger screen devices

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".StatisticActivity"
        android:label="Statistiques"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LegalActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_legal"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PalmaresActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_palmares"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >


    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FacebookActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_facebook"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Main3Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main3"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

But tablets are still not able to find the app on the playstore and when you send a link to the tablet to download the app, the playstore says it is not compatible

Comment: post your manifest

Comment: Most likely you have defined some permissions that are not available on tablets. Similar question [My android app is not available for tablets on google play](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837041/my-android-app-is-not-available-for-tablets-on-google-play)

Comment: I just updated my post with the entire manifest

Answer (score 1):

Do the tablets have GSM? I think the problem is this :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"  />
```

this will depend on feature android.hardware.telephony - so you need to set this to optional